# Best data structure to hold a group of coordinates inside a really big rectangle?

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, game-engine

I have an abstract representation of a map with, lets say, 5.000.000 different integer coordinates on the X and Y coordinates, so it is a really big 2d rectangle.

And then, inside that variable-sized rectangle, I have several objects (characters, monsters, npcs). A player can select a position of this rectangle, and I have to check if there is a monster or a character on said position.

So far, I made a custom class called GameMatrix with columns and rows, and said columns has 3000x2000 positions (the area view of a character).

When a player of my game clicks on said coordinate, I have to do a `foreach()` of every element inside the matrix, and most of the times it is empty.

Is there a better way to solve this? Specifically, I am asking on what is the best way to, having a really big rectangle and a coordinate, check if there are objects inside said coordinate in an efficient way.

Forgot to mention, but this is done in the server-side several times per miliseconds. So I need a lot of performance.

**Edit:** Forgot to mention, I am using C#.

Comment: Why "I have to do a foreach() of every element inside "? If you know position just check what is at given position... or I'm missing something.

Comment: I know the position of the player, but when the player casts a spell or interacts with another player who isn't on the same position, it has to check if there is a player on the position. Check out this video so you have an idea: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EwwCpUrRKs Spells are casted all the time, and they are casted on a position and I have to check if there is a player on said position.

Comment: Side note: "several times per miliseconds" and "server-side" assume you have insanely low ping time... Spending time on time synchronization/dead reconning and similar things may be more important that optimizing search through 1-50 objects you have currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a quad-tree implementation, unless the number of items in the grid is really small (like a couple of dozens items), in which case a linear search (brute force inspecting all of them at the same time) is probably the best choice.

See here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Note that a quad tree can be queried very quickly and efficiently, but updates are a bit more costly, that is if your items move a lot across your map, this becomes more complicated to do with a good performance.

Comment: Yes, the players move all the time.

Comment: +1 Linear search through all (like 10?) game objects would be likley enough for quite some time. Quadtree or any other complicated structure may be needed much later (and unlikely if you stay in very small world).

Comment: @Pacha: if the players move relatively slow (they don't jump around the map all the time), updates in a quadtree are cheap, because most of the time they stay in the same cell (a rectangular set of positions) - and if they cross the bounding box, you need to find the neighbouring cell, only, which can be implemented efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend just trying the simplest solution first and worry about the optimization later.

Try using an array. Improve your solution as you go. A list or hash map might be interesting too depending on your setup.

Comment: yes you should use a [jagged-array](http://www.dotnetperls.com/jagged-array) instead of a 2d array in your case, which has better performance.